# How to print NOT \sqsubseteq?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

Could anyone tell me a conventional way to print NOT `\sqsubseteq`?

Comment: Do you want not (a subset or equal) or a subset but not equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to prefix the symbol with `\not`, as in `\not\sqsubseteq`. Alternatively, [`pxfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pxfonts) provides `\nsqsubseteq`.

For more symbols in LaTeX, peruse Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive).

Comment: More precisely, one should use `{\not\sqsubseteq}` with the surrounding brackets, otherwise the placement of the bar can vary. Or even `{\not\!\sqsubseteq}` to place the bar closer to the middle.
Also, `pxfonts` will change the font of the whole document.